# Python PyCallGraph.PyCallGraphException Graphviz

Tags: python, python-3.x, graphviz, pycallgraph

Im trying to use the `pycallgraph` library for Python on my Windows commandline

```
from pycallgraph import PyCall Graph
from pycallgraph.output import GraphvizOutput

with PyCallGraph(output=GraphvizOutput()):
    for i in range(0,11):
        print(str(i) + " times looped")
```

After executing this i get the following error:
'The command "{}" is required to be in your path.'.format(cmd))
pycallgraph.exceptions.PyCallGraphException: The command "dot" is required to be in your path.

I know that i need to install dot, but i don't know how to do it

Comment: In case somebody else is stumped (I noticed your question is almost 10 months old), check [this](https://github.com/gak/pycallgraph/issues/177) out; using brew instead of pip3 worked for me but they outline a couple of other potential issues.